# asp.net mvc action link with id before action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

I have the following route config in my mvc4 project:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "single",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Details" },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "singleCreate",
            url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "GalleryImage", action = "Create" },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and now i would like to create a link to the route "singleCreate".

I've tried this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Image", "Create", "GalleryImage", new { id = Model.Id }, null)
```

but this doesn't work as I expected. I get a Link without an action which looks like this:

```
/GalleryImage/cc66338c-6500-4967-8be9-a8a6948f22c4
```

The link should be like this:

```
/GalleryImage/cc66338c-6500-4967-8be9-a8a6948f22c4/Create
```

Has anyone already created such a link and can give me some suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Add Image", "singleCreate", new { controller = "GalleryImage", action = "Create", id = Model.Id })
```

Comment: I've tried that. Now I get a link to the wrong controller: http://localhost:4427/Gallery/cc66338c-6500-4967-8be9-a8a6948f22c4

Comment: Whats really surprising is when I User a different action for ActionLink the Action is correctly appended on the end of the link. I have to rename my view then but then everything works. I do not understand what goes wrong if I leave the views in original.

Comment: Still no luck: /GalleryImage/cc66338c-6500-4967-8be9-a8a6948f22c4